# Can I set multiple default values for Semantic UI's "Multiple Search Selection" type dropdown using HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Using Semantic UI. I'm looking for a way to define the default selected values in HTML rather than using

```
set selected([value1, value2])
```

with JS.

I haven't found any documentation about how to accomplish this using plain HTML and jQuery. Is it a matter of updating option tag attribute values?

Comment: Put the `selected` attribute in the `<option>` tag. `<option value="foo" selected>Foo</option>`

Comment: [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#examples)